# Accessing route parameter in view with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I have a route set up like so:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/reset-password/{code}', array('as' => 'reset-password-confirm', 'uses' => 'UserController@resetPasswordConfirm'));
```

In my controller, I'm passing the route parameter to my action like so:

```
public function resetPasswordConfirm($code)
{
    // ...
}
```

I can then use `$code` in my controller as normal.

In my view I'm building a form which POSTs to the same controller action, and I need to somehow get `$code` into the view so it constructs the proper form action. At the moment I have this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('reset-password-confirm'))) }}
```

Because I'm not supplying the `$code` route parameter, the form is opened like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site.dev/reset-password/%7Bcode%7D" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Obviously, this doesn't match the route I've defined (due to `{code}` not existing) and route matching fails. I need to somehow get the route parameter into my view so I can use it with `Form::open()`. I've tried doing this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('reset-password-confirm', $code))) }}
```

But that just throws an exception saying `$code` is undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper way to send the `parameter` to the view is:

```
return View::make('viewname')->with('code', $code);
```

Or you may use:

```
return View::make('yourview', compact('code'));
```

So, the `$code` will be available in your view and you may use it in your form but you may also use following approach to access a `parameter` in the view:

```
// Laravel - Latest (use any one)
Route::Input('code');
Route::current()->getParameter('code');
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('code');

// Laravel - 4.0
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('code');
```

Comment: I've been looking all over the internet for this information. This is the only thread I've found it in. Thanks.

Comment: You are wlcome. Glad ot helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't clearly understand your question, but you can pass it to the view regularly (as you would pass any other variable, i.e.)

```
public function resetPasswordConfirm($code)
{
    return View::make('yourview')->with('code', $code);
}
```

and in the view $code will be defined:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('reset-password-confirm', $code))) }}
```

**or** just catch it  in your view directly from the Request object:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('reset-password-confirm', Request::segment(2) ))) }}
```

By the way, I think you could write your route also like this:

```
Route::any('reset-password/{code}', array('as' => 'reset-password-confirm', 'uses' => 'UserController@resetPasswordConfirm'));
```